# How to find out which process is eating that much memory?

Tags: unix, memory, memory-management, freebsd

Output of `# top -o size`

```
last pid: 61935;  load averages:  0.82,  0.44,  0.39                              up 10+13:28:42  16:49:43
152 processes: 2 running, 150 sleeping
CPU: 10.3% user,  0.0% nice,  1.8% system,  0.2% interrupt, 87.7% idle
Mem: 5180M Active, 14G Inact, 2962M Wired, 887M Cache, 2465M Buf, 83M Free
Swap: 512M Total, 26M Used, 486M Free, 5% Inuse

  PID USERNAME  THR PRI NICE   SIZE    RES STATE   C   TIME   WCPU COMMAND
 1471 mysql      62  44    0   763M   349M ucond   3 222:19 74.76% mysqld
 1171 root        4  44    0   645M   519M sbwait  0  20:56  3.86% tfs
41173 root        4  44    0   629M   516M sbwait  4  19:17  0.59% tfs
41350 root        4  44    0   585M   467M sbwait  7  15:17  0.10% tfs
36382 root        4  45    0   581M   401M sbwait  1 206:50  0.10% tfs
41157 root        4  44    0   551M   458M sbwait  5  16:23  0.98% tfs
36401 root        4  45    0   199M   108M uwait   2  17:50  0.00% tfs
36445 root        4  44    0   199M    98M uwait   4  20:11  0.00% tfs
36420 root        4  45    0   191M    98M uwait   4  19:57  0.00% tfs
 3491 root        9  45    0 79320K 41292K uwait   4  40:22  0.00% tfs_db
40690 root        1  44    0 29896K  4104K select  1   0:05  0.00% sshd
44636 root        1  44    0 29896K  3896K select  4   0:00  0.00% sshd
22224 root        1  44    0 29896K  3848K select  6   0:00  0.00% sshd
42956 root        1  44    0 29896K  3848K select  4   0:00  0.00% sshd
  909 bind       11  76    0 27308K 14396K kqread  1   0:00  0.00% named
 1586 root        1  44    0 26260K  3464K select  4   0:00  0.00% sshd
40590 root        4  45    0 23480K  7592K uwait   1   5:11  0.00% auth
 1472 root        1  44    0 22628K  8776K select  0   0:41  0.00% perl5.8.9
22229 root        1  44    0 20756K  2776K select  0   0:00  0.00% sftp-server
42960 root        1  44    0 20756K  2772K select  2   0:00  0.00% sftp-server
44638 root        1  44    0 10308K  2596K pause   2   0:00  0.00% csh
42958 root        1  47    0 10308K  1820K pause   3   0:00  0.00% csh
22227 root        1  48    0 10308K  1820K pause   0   0:00  0.00% csh
36443 root        1  57    0 10248K  1792K wait    0   0:00  0.00% bash
36418 root        1  51    0 10248K  1788K wait    2   0:00  0.00% bash
41171 root        1  63    0 10248K  1788K wait    0   0:00  0.00% bash
36399 root        1  50    0 10248K  1784K wait    2   0:00  0.00% bash
41155 root        1  56    0 10248K  1784K wait    0   0:00  0.00% bash
40588 root        1  76    0 10248K  1776K wait    6   0:00  0.00% bash
36380 root        1  50    0 10248K  1776K wait    2   0:00  0.00% bash
41348 root        1  54    0 10248K  1776K wait    0   0:00  0.00% bash
 1169 root        1  54    0 10248K  1772K wait    0   0:00  0.00% bash
 3485 root        1  76    0 10248K  1668K wait    4   0:00  0.00% bash
61934 root        1  44    0  9372K  2356K CPU4    4   0:00  0.00% top
 1185 mysql       1  76    0  8296K  1356K wait    3   0:00  0.00% sh
 1611 root        1  44    0  7976K  1372K nanslp  0   0:08  0.00% cron
  824 root        1  44    0  7048K  1328K select  0   0:03  0.00% syslogd
 1700 root        1  76    0  6916K  1052K ttyin   3   0:00  0.00% getty
 1703 root        1  76    0  6916K  1052K ttyin   2   0:00  0.00% getty
 1702 root        1  76    0  6916K  1052K ttyin   5   0:00  0.00% getty
 1706 root        1  76    0  6916K  1052K ttyin   0   0:00  0.00% getty
 1705 root        1  76    0  6916K  1052K ttyin   1   0:00  0.00% getty
 1701 root        1  76    0  6916K  1052K ttyin   6   0:00  0.00% getty
 1707 root        1  76    0  6916K  1052K ttyin   4   0:00  0.00% getty
 1704 root        1  76    0  6916K  1052K ttyin   7   0:00  0.00% getty
  490 root        1  44    0  3204K   556K select  1   0:00  0.00% devd
```

My game server lag so much and I have noticed that there is only 83M of free ram.

Its not just `top` because I have also tried to use other app:

```
# /usr/local/bin/freem
SYSTEM MEMORY INFORMATION:
mem_wire:        3104976896 (   2961MB) [ 12%] Wired: disabled for paging out
mem_active:  +   5440778240 (   5188MB) [ 21%] Active: recently referenced
mem_inactive:+  15324811264 (  14614MB) [ 61%] Inactive: recently not referenced
mem_cache:   +   1015689216 (    968MB) [  4%] Cached: almost avail. for allocation
mem_free:    +     86818816 (     82MB) [  0%] Free: fully available for allocation
mem_gap_vm:  +       946176 (      0MB) [  0%] Memory gap: UNKNOWN
-------------- ------------ ----------- ------
mem_all:     =  24974020608 (  23817MB) [100%] Total real memory managed
mem_gap_sys: +    772571136 (    736MB)        Memory gap: Kernel?!
-------------- ------------ -----------
mem_phys:    =  25746591744 (  24553MB)        Total real memory available
mem_gap_hw:  +     23212032 (     22MB)        Memory gap: Segment Mappings?!
-------------- ------------ -----------
mem_hw:      =  25769803776 (  24576MB)        Total real memory installed

SYSTEM MEMORY SUMMARY:
mem_used:        9342484480 (   8909MB) [ 36%] Logically used memory
mem_avail:   +  16427319296 (  15666MB) [ 63%] Logically available memory
-------------- ------------ ----------- ------
mem_total:   =  25769803776 (  24576MB) [100%] Logically total memory
```

As you can see, the output is similar:

`mem_free:    +     86818816 (     82MB) [  0%] Free: fully available for allocation`.

My dedicated has 24GB of RAM and it's pretty much for my game server.

**How can I find out which process is eating that amount of memory?**

I am using FreeBSD 8.2.

Comment: Memory allocation isn't as simple as you might think - modern OSes try not to waste memory by leaving it completely unallocated. Recently closed applications might have their memory preserved in case you want them to run again, etc...  If you actually need the memory, it'll be pulled from one of the allocated areas.  It doesn't look like you're anywhere close to being out of RAM.

Comment: @SamDufel I thought this one: `0%] Free: fully available for allocation` means that there is no space available for memory allocation?

Comment: Not entirely.  The general idea is that free memory is wasted memory, so your OS will try to use as much memory as it can for things like preloading applications you might want to use.  When you actually need the memory, it can be pulled from inactive / cache memory

Comment: @SamDufel Wow. Didn't know it works like this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to top's output, you are only using 5% of your swap. This means, you are *not* short on RAM -- whatever is slowing you down, it is not the memory shortage. If anything, I'd be suspecting mysqld -- not only was it quite busy, when you took the snapshot, it also accumulated quite a bit of CPU-time prior to that.

Perhaps, some frequently-running queries can be helped by a new index or two?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How can I add mysqls query index?

Comment: That's a separate topic -- and the answer would be too large to fit into a comment anyway. MySQL is a very popular database engine and there ought to be tutorials on query-optimization out there.

Comment: Late to the party but if anyone is looking at this answer one should know that SWAP is used if physical ram is full. So @Lucas was out of memory....

Comment: It is more complex than that, @MichaelP. For example, the kernel may have used swap because there was RAM-shortage _earlier_. It could also page certain pages out just in case -- because there is swap available, and it _might_ need real RAM soon. In this particular case, top lists 2.4G as "buffers" -- which also indicates, there is no RAM-shortage currently.